# SWT / JFace Scrollview not scrolling

Tags: java, swt, scrollview, jface

I have two tabs with their own respective views. The tabview itself is in a scrollview. For some reason, the scrollbars don't appear for the larger tab. I set up the (working) tabview like so:

```
public CustomerTab(Composite arg1, int arg2) throws SQLException {
    super(arg1, arg2);

    layout = new org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout(GridData.FILL_BOTH, false);
    layout.numColumns = 1;
    this.setLayout(layout);
```

The one, that's not causing the scrollbars to appear, starts like so:

```
public InvoiceTab(Composite parent, int arg2) throws Exception {

    super(parent, arg2);

    // new gridlayout and asign to this tab
    gridLayout = new org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout(GridData.FILL_BOTH, false);
    gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
    this.setLayout(gridLayout);
```

In my application, I configure the shell:

```
@Override protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {

    super.configureShell(shell);
    shell.setSize(1130, 530);
    setShellStyle(SWT.SHELL_TRIM & (~SWT.RESIZE));
}
```

and create the scrollview this way:

```
@Override protected Control createContents (Composite parent) {

    scrolledComp = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    mainContent = new Composite(scrolledComp, SWT.NONE);
    mainContent.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    mainTabView = null;
    mainTabView = new MainTabView(mainContent);

    scrolledComp.setContent(mainContent);
    scrolledComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    scrolledComp.setExpandVertical(true);
    scrolledComp.setMinSize(1100, 500);

    return mainTabView;
}
```

What happens, is that the scrollview just displays as far the 500 go, but no content below, no scrollbars. Can anybody see, what I'm doing wrong?

Thanx in advance,
Marcus

Comment: Have you tried: `scrolledComp.setMinSize(mainContent.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT))`?

Comment: Just a side note: The first argument for `GridLayout` is  `numColumns`. Not sure why you use `GridData.FILL_BOTH`.

Comment: GridData.FILL_BOTH was a fix at the wrong place, wasn't there before 8) Thanx, got it to work with computeSize. Wouldn't you like to make that an answer?

Comment: Always a pleasure working with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set you minimum height manually to 500, the `ScrolledComposite` doesn't know better.

You should use the "real" size of the content as minimum size. You can use the following code:

```
scrolledComp.setContent(mainContent);
scrolledComp.setExpandHorizontal(true);
scrolledComp.setExpandVertical(true);
scrolledComp.setMinSize(mainContent.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
```

Comment: short one: is there a way to suppress the scrolls bars, not matter what?

Comment: @MarcusToepper After some googling it seems that this isn't possible. But I might be wrong...

Comment: didn't fin anything either. now, the 'problem' is, that the scrollview scrolls for the smaller view, too. Just an inconvenience, but not nice none the less. I guess, a workaround would be to recalculate the size size on tab change and redraw the scrollview, but that seems an awful lot just to get rid of some extra space...

Comment: @MarcusToepper I didn't really understand that.

Comment: I have three tabs. The computeSize() sets the height of the scrollview to the largest one of the three. Therefore, the two smaller ones have some extra blank space at the bottom, you can scroll through. Not nice, but as you can't simply suppress the scrollbars, the above mentioned idea might do.

Comment: but as a simple solution: as the two other tabs each feature a table, I've set grabExcessVerticalSpace for those views, so that does the trick, if not really nice, though 8) Thanx again!

Comment: @MarcusToepper Didn't really help with that one ;) Glad it works though.